# How do I update (not overwrite) a record in Elasticsearch using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Writing a Lambda, I am grabbing a file from S3 and sending it to Elasticsearch. When I attached the file using pipeline-attachment, it attaches correctly but overwrites all my fields. How do I just attach the file to my record while maintaining my previous fields in my response?  Can't find the documentation for this action.

I am using the Elasticsearch.index to initially attach the file, which works but overwrites all my other fields. I have tried the Elasticsearch.update, but cant get it to work.

```
s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key}, function (err, data) {
               if (err) {
                        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                        context.fail();
               } else {
                  console.log('data: ', data); // successful response
                  var attachment = data.Body.toString('base64'); 
                  console.log('attachment: ', attachment);
                  elasticsearch.index(
                 {
                       index: 'files',
                       pipeline: 'attachment',
                       type: 'file',
                       id: key,
                       body: {
                              data: attachment
                             }
                 },
                   function (error, resp) {
                       if (error) {
                          console.trace('index error!', error);
                       } else {
                          console.log('index response', resp);
                          context.succeed();
                       }
                   }
                   );
                }
           });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Update API does not support ingest pipelines, but I figured out a way around this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17895#issuecomment-357661426

Comment: I see. Follow these steps?
1. first use the Index API to index the data into a temporary index using the ingestion pipeline (to apply the transformations, renaming, etc)
2. then to read the data from that temporary index
3. and finally to use the Update API (doc/script upsert) to update the real index with the transformed data read from the temporary index.
Since I have the inital index setup, what would my code look like for the temp and then the update to combine them?